# Setinterval Function Repeating the HTML contents

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a table row of contents which is fetched from API while im using setinterval function it just repeating the updated table row content down.

For eg: (This is an example output not actual)

Assume that i have a content

```
John price 2000
```

After the time interval of 1 second it should update the new value from API like

```
John price 2200
```

But what I'm getting is everytime it refreshes it just adding down like

```
John price 2000
John price 2200
John price 2120 ......
```

My Code:

```html
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Coin</th>
          <th>Symbol</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody id="details">

  <tbody>
    </table>
```

```js
var data, len, len1, name, symbol, currency, price;

const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";

async function get_data_from_api() {

  const response = await fetch(api_url);

  data = await response.json();

  len = Object.keys(data["markets"]).length;
  len1 = Object.keys(data["assets"]).length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
      if (data['markets'][i]['baseMarket'] == data['assets'][j]['type'] && data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'] == "inr") {

        name = data['assets'][j]['name'];
        symbol = data['assets'][j]['type'];
        currency = data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'];
        price = data['markets'][i]['buy'];
        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + symbol + "</td><td>" + currency + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>";
      }
    }
  }
}

get_data_from_api();

setInterval(get_data_from_api, 1000);
```

Comment: `+=` concatenates

Comment: Just replace += with = in your innerHTML?

Comment: tried that but if i remove += means nothing is showing on my table its just empty idk what's the issue. but if i use += means output showing correctly.

Comment: @Bravo I just answered the question, this should work.

Comment: I think if you provide the example of data you fetched from your API. It would help people to understand your question and provide an answer easily.

Comment: @ikhvjs - it's easy to get the data - the URL is in the question

Comment: @Bravo, Thanks. I wonder why no one makes an executable answer then. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @ikhvjs - because that API doesn't allow stacksnippets access :p

Comment: @Bravo, it would be easy to make a `fakefetch()` with the data, right?

Comment: yes and no - the data is 179,319 bytes long - I'm not sure you could have a snippet with that much data in it :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your code keeps adding to the table is because you only did

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += " ..... "
```

So, of course that only adds

The naive solution is to add code BEFORE the loops that clears innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = ""
```

A far better solution would be to initialise a string variable before the loops, add to the string inside the loops, then update innerHTML *once* after the loops

```
const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";

async function get_data_from_api() {

    const response = await fetch(api_url);

    const data = await response.json();

    const len = Object.keys(data["markets"]).length;
    const len1 = Object.keys(data["assets"]).length;

    // this will hold the new HTML
    let html = "";
    
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
            if (data['markets'][i]['baseMarket'] == data['assets'][j]['type'] && data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'] == "inr") {
                const name = data['assets'][j]['name'];
                const symbol = data['assets'][j]['type'];
                const currency = data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'];
                const price = data['markets'][i]['buy'];
                html += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + symbol + "</td><td>" + currency + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    // we have the new HTML - update the DOM only once per API call
    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = html;
}
```

> (I took the liberty of declaring the variables where they are needed rather than globally)

Now: Here's an alternative that cleans up the for loops using array methods like flatMap, filter, map

```
const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";
async function get_data_from_api() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = Object.values(data.markets)
            .flatMap((market) =>
                Object.values(data.assets)
                                   // your if condition
                .filter((asset) => market.baseMarket == asset.type && market.quoteMarket == 'inr')
                .map((asset) => {
                    const { name, type: symbol } = asset;
                    const { quoteMarket: currency, buy: price } = market;
                    return `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${symbol}</td><td>${currency}</td><td>${price}</td></tr>`;
                })
            ).join('');
    } catch(error) {
        // handle error
    }
    setTimeout(get_data_from_api, 1000);
}

get_data_from_api();
```

---

Not sure, but this code may update just the price

```
const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";
async function get_data_from_api() {
    try {
        const target = document.getElementById('details');
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const addedHtml = Object.values(data.markets)
            .flatMap((market) =>
                Object.values(data.assets)
                                   // your if condition
                .filter((asset) => market.baseMarket == asset.type && market.quoteMarket == 'inr')
                .map((asset) => {
                    const { name, type: symbol } = asset;
                    const { quoteMarket: currency, buy: price } = market;
                    return { id, name, symbol, currency, price };
                })
            )
            .map(({ name, symbol, currency, price }) => {
                const id = `${name}${symbol}${currency}`;
                let el = target.querySelector(`#${id}`);
                if (el) {
                    el.textContent = price;
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${symbol}</td><td>${currency}</td><td id="${id}">${price}</td></tr>`;
                }
            });
        if (addedHTML.length) {
            target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addedHtml.join(''));
        }
    } catch(error) {
        // handle error
    }
    setTimeout(get_data_from_api, 1000);
}

get_data_from_api();
```

Comment: EError occured in my console which is "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.values(...).flatmap is not a function
    at get_data_from_api"

Comment: @harish - should've been `flatMap` ... my bad

Comment: The question was "issue with the code" and the approved answer was "How to write the best code"

Comment: @harish, please have a look at my answer. It would help you as well.

Comment: @Bravo It was really funny. The question was the logical error he had with his code. He asked why his records are getting appended to the  existing one rather than clearing the existing and creating new. But this answer was like how this code can be improved to more efficient level.

Comment: @Bravo Reason for downvote: Answer didnt solved the issue mentioned in the question. Question was "why the nodes are getting appended to the existing element". This has not even addressed in the answer.

Comment: @Bravo That was already covered in my answer.

Comment: @Nitheesh - if you still having a problem with the fact that this answer is the accepted one - take it up with OP or report it or, I don't know 

Answer (score 1):

Besides the accepted answer. I also recommend you use a while loop with a `wait` function below instead of `setInterval`.

setInterval may call the API unnecessarily. For example. first time call the api, the api takes one second to respond, at the same time you call the the api second time it respond with only 100ms and actually, you will not see the result of the first time because the second call update the first call immediatlely.

```js
const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";

const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async function run() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(api_url);
      const data = await response.json();
      //html jobs.....
      await wait(1000);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      continue;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: why? I mean, sure, it won't block the main thread or anything ... but ... why? what is the advantage

Comment: @Bravo, setInterval may call the API unnecessarily. For example. first time call the api, the api takes one second to respond, at the same time you call the the api second time it respond with only 100ms and actually, you will not see the result of the first time because the second call update the first call immediatlely.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - I was wondering, not criticising

Comment: @Bravo, sure, we are just discussing.

Comment: though ... you could do the same with a `setTimeout`

Comment: @Bravo, what do you mean? I did use `setTimeout` for the `wait` function.

Comment: yeah, I know ... but ... look at my answer ... I took your valid point and made it work with just a `setTimeout`

Comment: not sure what you mean, the setTimeout won't **begin** until the fetch has completed

Comment: @Bravo, I see your point.  It could do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending contents to the node with

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+symbol+"</td><td>"+currency+"</td><td>"+price+"</td></tr>";
```

Before appending that you have to set the content to empty outside the loop if you have multiple nodes that satisfies the condition.

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "";
```

If there is only one single node that satisfies the condition just assign the value with

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+symbol+"</td><td>"+currency+"</td><td>"+price+"</td></tr>";
```

Working solution will be something like this.

```
var data, len, len1, name, symbol, currency, price;

const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";

async function get_data_from_api() {

  const response = await fetch(api_url);

  document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = '';

  data = await response.json();

  len = Object.keys(data["markets"]).length;
  len1 = Object.keys(data["assets"]).length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
      if (data['markets'][i]['baseMarket'] == data['assets'][j]['type'] && data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'] == "inr") {

        name = data['assets'][j]['name'];
        symbol = data['assets'][j]['type'];
        currency = data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'];
        price = data['markets'][i]['buy'];
        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + symbol + "</td><td>" + currency + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>";
      }
    }
  }
}

get_data_from_api();

setInterval(get_data_from_api, 1000);
```

Comment: @Nitheesh yeah but i have multiple datas coming from my API using forloop so i cant put '='

Comment: Bravo i didn't check your answer it got deleted b4 i get into it

Comment: is there any option to referesh the price details alone? Currently Its refreshing all. Any idea ?